# Filtering gridview Between dates does not get records for Date To

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to filter a gridview to show orders between specific dates. I managed to make it work but it does not show the records for the Date To. It only shows the between of that dates. The records that exist in Date from shows up...

```
 <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EDS_Orders" runat="server" EnableUpdate="true" EnableFlattening="False"  OrderBy="it.Order_date ASC"
                      ConnectionString="name=Bohemian1Entities" DefaultContainerName="Bohemian1Entities" EntitySetName="t_customer_orders"
                      Where="it.UserName is not null and (it.Order_date Between @DateFrom AND @DateTo) AND (it.UserName Like '%' + @UserName +  '%') " >
    <WhereParameters>                                                     

         <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlDateFrom" Name="DateFrom" 
         Type="DateTime" DefaultValue="%"/>
         <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlDateTo" Name="DateTo" 
         Type="DateTime" DefaultValue="%"/>
         <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlCustomers" Name="UserName" PropertyName="Text" 
         Type="String" DefaultValue="%"/>

    </WhereParameters>

</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Comment: For example if my date to is 28/03/2013 the records shows up until 27/03/2103

Comment: What type of `Order_date` column? Is it `Date` or `DateTime`? Does it have any not zero time fraction value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to rewrite `Where` clause as below:

```
Where="it.UserName is not null and (CAST(it.Order_date AS DATE) Between @DateFrom AND @DateTo) 
    AND (it.UserName Like '%' + @UserName + '%')"
```